# combobox java help to recover ID for selectedItem

Tags: java

I 'm beginner in java and I want to use a combobox on two tables (vendor ,piece ) I load my provider combobox but I would like when I click the vendor that I can get its ID and insert it in piece.my problem is the code to retrieve the Vendor ID selected in the combobox, please help me, this is my code:

```
private void Fillcombo(){

 String sql ="select * from fournisseur";
 try{

     stm = conn.obtenirconnexion().createStatement();
     Rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
     while(Rs.next()){
           String f= Rs.getString("nomFournisseur");
           txt_f.addItem(f);
     }
 }catch(Exception e){ 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
 }
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem? what did you expect to get and what do you actually get?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to be able to render a description/name about the Vendor in the combobox but when you select a description/name in the combobox,  you want to be able to retrieve the Vendor object.

JCombobox comes naturally with it. You can add objects other than String as items in JCombobox, JCombobox will use the toString() method of the object to render it, while JCombobox.getSeletecedItem() will still give you the full object.

So what you can do: 1) Define a Vendor class (you can do the same for your piece class) 2) Create Vendor objects based with data that you loaded from the data base 3) Override the toString() method of Vendor to the text that you want to show in the JCombobox 4) add the vendor objects into JCombobox 5) Do whatever you need to do with the selected Vendor

Example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Vendor {
String name;
int ID;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

public Vendor(String name, int ID) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ID = ID;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vendor[] vendors = {new Vendor("Apple", 1)
            , new Vendor("Microsoft", 2)
            , new Vendor("Google", 3)};

    final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(vendors);

    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.add(comboBox);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.pack();

    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Vendor selectedVendor = (Vendor) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(selectedVendor.name + ", " + selectedVendor.ID);
            // do whatever here you need to do with the ID of vendor
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: thank Mr Bond :  I use netbenas I want to retrieve the id when I select a vendor in my combobox; I need the id for the insert in another table.if I can have a full example code because I debuted in java thank you!!!Be tolerant, I speak French ,my English is poor, thank you!

Comment: @Diomanez you are welcome. The code I gave is a full running example, you can replace the comment with your logic to insert the id into the table you mentioned.